# cancel file uploading with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, nsurlconnection

I've got `NSURLConnection` with timeout  = 30s which is uploading an image on server.
If connection is horrible and call delegate method `didFailWithError:` then i need to cancel current connection.
But if i just call the `[myConnection cancel]` connection will still alive but will not call delegates methods (apple docs say it - `NSURLConnection` `cancel` method). And i want to abort connection but not only remove delegate methods. How i can do what?

**upd:**
My problem is if connection is fails by timeout - in business logic i must recreate connection with similar request. If i have got horrible connection for 1 min and after that connection will be good - server will get a lot of (about 3 times retry count) photos. But first 2 connections is canceled. –

At the moment i make "dirty hack" like "if it's photo uploading request" - do not retry recreate connection.

Comment: I use Charles application for traffic-analysis. And i see what connection is still uploading photo on server after i call cancel to it.

Comment: My problem is if connection is fails by timeout - in business logic i must recreate connection with similar request. If i have got horrible connection  for 1 min and after that connection will be good - server will get a lot of (about 3 times retry count) photos. But first 2 connections is canceled.

Comment: For your timed out requests, are you seeing `didSendBodyData` called? Are you seeing `didReceiveResponse`? Where precisely is it timing out? Is the timed-out request's file on the server complete?

Answer (score 1):

I do a ton of network stuff and don't recall a scenario where everything was successfully received but the iOS app timed out. I'm trying to grok the scenario you describe, where you're seeing this happen a lot and I'm not seeing how that would happen. We might need to see some of your code.

Regardless, when you `cancel` a `NSURLConnection`, it not only stops the delegate methods from being called, but it stops the upload, too. I just did a test:

- I attempting to upload a 20mb file (non-`chunked` request);
- At the 1mb mark (as identified by `didSendBodyData`), I canceled the connection (by calling `[connection cancel]`);
- I immediately stopped receiving any delegate messages at that point;
- Looking at Charles, I'm only seeing 1.3mb of data in the hex log of the request. When I look at the "Network" tab of the Mac OS "Activity Monitor" and looking at by "Sent Bytes", it's at 2.1mb uploaded.

So canceling a connection will stop further data from being sent. Perhaps if there is some transmission in progress that still gets out (that's the asynchronous world we live it), but the it's not true to conclude that canceled connections will routinely send their full HTTP request. There must be something about the nature of the timeout that is unique to your environment.

In terms of your immediate problem, I might suggest that when uploading a file that the iOS app assign some unique identifier to the upload so that the server code can immediately recognize duplicate requests and handle them appropriately. But the question is why you are seeing so many time-outs and notably ones where the request appears to be successfully received in toto, but the response is not. That's very curious.

Comment: "We might need to see some of your code." - it will be a problem, cuz there is a lot of code in different places. Developer who do it is really love spaghetti pattern. But it's an other story..) About your research with cancel method: in average size of images about 200kb. As you say - 1mb mark - you call cancel, but totally upload data size was 1.3-2.1mb. Could it be my trouble, how do you think?

Comment: About "request received/response is not" - request not received at time i'm cancel it. It just in progress at this time.

Comment: I found a small fix for my case(upd in my question). And now it's just an interesting case..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49998/discussion-between-rob-and-evgeniy-s)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot forcefully abort an ongoing connection.
In case if connection is not yet started cancel and **unscheduleFromRunLoop** for the **NSURLConnection** will work.

Comment: Is there any proof for "You cannot forcefully abort an ongoing connection"?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following step

```
[myConnection cancel];
myConnection = nil;
```

Might be helpful in your case and If this step is not working then also try with `myConnection.delegate = nil;`

Comment: I try it. myConnection is not nil and it exactly needed connection. Also i do release before set to nil, cuz it's 2009 year code and it use MRC :)

Comment: [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request_
                                                  delegate:self
                                          startImmediately:YES];

Comment: I don't think that setting your local reference to a connection to `nil` in ARC (or calling `release` in MRC) will ever fix this problem. You're resolving your strong reference to the object, but connection objects retain themselves for the duration of the request, and relieving your app's strong reference will not change that. Don't get me wrong: I think you're right that you should remove any strong reference you have to ensure resources are recovered as soon as possible, but it won't possibly solve Evgeniy's problem.